How to fix order of inherited subclasses in Python Dataclass
I am trying to create a Dataclass for a Latitude&Longitude using inherited subclasses of Latitude and Longitude. But the order of the inherited subclasses is incorrect.
from dataclasses import dataclass


# Custom TypeValidator https://gist.github.com/rnag/db6bf83d9ca19dfe897d6ccabd4e2570
from validators import TypeValidator

@dataclass
class Latitude:
    lat: float | int = TypeValidator()

    def __post_init__(self):
        if not -90 <= self.lat <= 90:
            raise ValueError('Lat must be from -90 to 90')


@dataclass
class Longitude:
    lon: float | int = TypeValidator()

    def __post_init__(self):
        if not -180 <= self.lon <= 180:
            raise ValueError('Lon must be from -180 to 180')

@dataclass
class LatLonPoint(Latitude,Longitude):
    pass

But it puts the lon first:
print(LatLonPoint(1,1))

LatLonPoint(lon=1, lat=1)
One reason for creating it like this was I was trying to fix post init validation by creating the subclasses for Lat and Lon. As I thought that would mean the subclass is reinitialised every time the value is updated. But this introduced this ordering problem. I did a bit of reading about MRO. But is there a way to fix the order without introducing kw_only=True?

You are both taking the wrong approach and mixing concepts in there.
It is really very little likely you will need, for any practical purposes, os specialized subclasses for Latitude and Longitude (although, yes, they could have some use).
Second: that is not how Object Oriented subclassing works: your class either IS what their superclasses are - in this case it means your LatLonPoint should simultaneously "be" both a Latitude and a Longitude coordinates. Or, it can own other classes in a relation - then your LatLonPoint will have a Latitude and a Longitude.
That is what you should aim at.
Another thing that doesn't make sense there: you want Latitude to BE a value, not to have a ".lat"  value. So, if you are really going for it, you could create classes that inherit from float - and them forget about dataclasses: they are a mechanism to suppress the boilerplate in a lot of use cases - but not meant for when one wants to specialize a class.
Without separate latitude and longitude classes, you could have latitude and longitude attributes on a LatLongPoint as properties - that would be the shorter and straightforward way of working with this in Python. These are feasible as dataclasses, but other tooling like typecheckers might complain, as the fields won't  contain a proper instance of float as the default value.
Inheriting from float has some peculiarities, and is usually thought of as more advanced topic - but it will be closer to what you where doing.
And, just to make sure it is understood: there is no sense in inheriting  Latitude and Longitude as you are doing.
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


# A common float specialization will avoid code duplication:
class CoordPoint(float):
    min = 0.0
    max = 0.0
    name = "Abstract coord point"
    def __new__(cls, value):
        instance = super().__new__(cls, value)
        instance._check_limits()
        return instance
    
    def _check_limits(self):
        # we _ARE_ a float, so "self"  can be used directly for the value:
        if not self.min <= self <= self.max: 
            raise ValueError(f"{self.name} must be from {self.min} to {self.max}")
    # you could specalize aritmetic operations like __add__ and __sub__
    # so that operations coud onl be performed with the same class,
    # and would return an instance of the correct class as well.
    # (so, no adding longitude and latitude objects allowed)
    # That is easy to do if needed, but would be overkill for 99.9% of uses
    
    # example:
    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, type(self)):
            raise TypeError("...")
        return type(self)(super().__add__(other))
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({float(self)})"
    
    
# Now, we leverage the power of O.O. to have
# Lat and Long classes with minimal code and boilerplate:

class Latitude(CoordPoint):
    min = -90
    max = 90
    name = "Lat"
    

class Longitude(CoordPoint):
    min = -180
    max = 180
    name = "Coord"


@dataclass
class LatLonPoint:
    # inherit nothing, just indicate the data types, and let 
    # dataclass do its magic!
    lat: Latitude
    lon: Longitude
    
    # dataclasses don't try to coerce the given input values
    # into instances of the type given to each field.
    # ths post init code can do this:
    def __post_init__(self):
        for field_name, field in self.__dataclass_fields__.items():
            setattr(self, field_name, field.type(getattr(self, field_name)))



Thanks for the feedback. The reason for having Latitude and Longitude separately defined was to implement the value checks only once. In addition to the LatLonPoint, I have a bounding box with four separate values for north, south, east and west. Being Lats and Lons respectively. And maybe some more superclasses. So I didn't want to repeat the value checks. I now get your point about how my code isn't correct inheritance.

Fine. I had added working code that will look pertty even to type checkers now - there is some semantic value to doing this instead of just using "properties"

Thanks. I also like how this way the custom float leverages the built-in function to convert an object to a floating point.
